# Как выполнить тайм-аут в цикле, не заблочив GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, gui, таймер, gtk3

Есть код, где незапущенные боксы sandboxie помечены красным. В функции `start_btn()` происходит проверка CheckButton'ов и последующий запуск отмеченных, с моментальной окраской лейбла в зелёный. В чём вопрос - как сделать, чтобы после строки
`self.builder.get_object(f"status_label_{box}").set_markup("бла бла бла")`
был тайм-аут в N секунд перед повторным вызовом функции `start_box()` , запускающей боксы в цикле, но при этом этот тайм-аут не должен блочить GUI, то бишь `time.sleep()` отлетает сразу

```
import gi
import os

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib

sandboxie_path = "C:/Program Files/Sandboxie-Plus/Start.exe"  # Путь к Start.exe
Steam_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steam.exe"  # Путь к steam.exe
tn_host = "127.0.0.1"
port_list = ["2121", "2122", "2123", "2124", "2125", "2126"]
server_list = ["85.88.162.140:27031"]
check_list = []


def start_box(box_num, tn_port, server, sandbox_path, steam_path):
    os.popen(f'"{sandbox_path}" /box:{box_num} "{steam_path}" -applaunch 730 -netconport {tn_port} -novid '
             f'-window -nosound +fps_max 30 -w 640 -h 480 +left connect {server}')


class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        gladeFile = "res/csgo.glade"
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(gladeFile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        window = self.builder.get_object("main")
        window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        window.show()

    def red_mark(self):
        for num in range(1, 7):
            self.builder.get_object(f"status_label_{num}").set_markup("<span background='#FA6DA4' "
                                                                      "foreground='#000000'>OFF</span>")

    def start_btn(self, widget):
        for box in range(1, 7):
            if self.builder.get_object(f"check_btn_{box}").get_active():
                start_box(box, port_list[box - 1], server_list[0], sandboxie_path, Steam_path)
                self.builder.get_object(f"status_label_{box}").set_markup("<span background='#76EE98' "
                                                                          "foreground='#000000'>ON</span>")
                # Тайм-аут на N секунд


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.red_mark()
    Gtk.main()
```

[image: Все боксы]
[image: Оба запущены]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

Перевёл покраску лейбла `self.builder.get_object(f"status_label_{box_num}").set_markup("<span background='#76EE98' foreground='#000000'>ON</span>")` в функцию `start_box()`, а в цикл в функции `start_btn()` добавил `bool` счётчик с начальным значением `False` и разделил цикл на два условия, так чтобы первый попавшийся `True` переключал счётчик на `True` и запускал первый выбранный бокс моментально, а следующие за ним с интервалом в 15 секунд с помощью `threading.Timer`.

Вот так всё выглядит на данный момент

```
    def start_btn(self, widget):
        counter = False
        for box in range(1, 7):
            if self.builder.get_object(f"check_btn_{box}").get_active() and not counter:
                counter = True
                self.start_box(box, port_list[box - 1], server_list[0], sandboxie_path, Steam_path)
                # self.builder.get_object(f"status_label_{box}").set_markup("<span background='#76EE98' "
                #                                                           "foreground='#000000'>ON</span>")
            elif self.builder.get_object(f"check_btn_{box}").get_active() and counter:
                threading.Timer(15, self.start_box,
                                (box, port_list[box - 1], server_list[0], sandboxie_path, Steam_path)).start()
```